# Uploading files in pipeline with wildcard cURL

Tags: curl, google-cloud-platform, pipeline

I am currently running a pipeline that relies on Google Cloud Platform for building a file. we want to automate the last step which is the file upload.

```
   - "gcloud compute ssh build-server-turnoff-when-unused --zone=europe-west4-a --command 'cd /mnt/disks/sdb/Project/ci_dev/tmp/deploy/images/project && curl -F 'image=@*.raucb' http://upload.url.com/upload'"
```

Now the issue is that it looks that curl -F doesn't accept wildcards, is it possible to get this done?

Comment: Is making a tar or a loop suitable for you?

Comment: Look at this https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60360/use-curl-to-download-images-from-website-using-wildcard

Comment: I was considering to write a bash script to make a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your command has two sets of ' ' one inside another without backspaces

In any case,

```
gcloud compute ssh build-server-turnoff-when-unused --zone=europe-west4-a --command "bash -c 'cd /mnt/disks/sdb/Project/ci_dev/tmp/deploy/images/project && for fileimg in *.raucb; do curl -F image="\${fileimg}" http://upload.url.com/upload ; done '"
```

Notes:

- I use "bash -c" to pass to --command so it only spawns a single process remotely (avoid issues with environment)
- `cd &&` instead of `cd ;` so that if cd fails, the for does not run
- double `"` inside single `'` inside double `"` to avoid excess escaping (alternate quotes trick)
- file extension not needed in foreach cycle as with `for fileimg in *.raucb` the var $fileimg will contain full filename
- had to quote the $ for the variable as `\$` or it gets interpreted by parent shell

Comment: It looks like and I still need to test this that curl -F cannot function in this loop and turns into a normal curl in the for loop. Probably cause curl -F requires 'image=@/path/to/file'. I will test this later this afternoon.

Comment: Oh, right, if it requires @ then it's possible to just add it. `image="@\${fileimg}"`  
  Also I forgot that this is in a YAML, I tested it in a shelll. Let me know how the ttest goes...

Comment: I got it working but somehow it breaks in the bitbucket pipeline no clue why.